# How to fix this ERROR: set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I try to use dblink in postgresql-8.3.23
and i got error when i use function dblink_send_query 
the code and error is below:

```
testdblink=# SELECT dblink_send_query('myconn', 'SELECT * FROM testjoindblink2');
ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
```

Please help
Thanks
Lalida